# Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) Java Swing Look and Feel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, osx-yosemite, look-and-feel

When I launch a java application using Swing for the GUI, I notice on Mac that Swing still renders the "old" Mac UI (10.9 and older). Since Oracle is now responsible to write the JRE for Mac OS X - where can I find any new UI?

Or are there any alternatives out there?

Comment: Actually, as I understand it, Apple is still responsible for providing the look and feel and native integration elements, Oracle provides the core JVM implementation

Comment: @MadProgrammer That would explain how we got screwed. Seeing as Apple now hate Java, they probably deliberately left Java apps looking old even though they updated the look for everything else.

Comment: @Trejkaz Apple hates everybody, even it's users it seems

Comment: Would Nimbus be better for you than the Mac OS System L&F ?

Comment: Apple added new Look and Feel in OS X 10.11

Answer (score 1):

This spiked my curiosity since it also bothers me.
@MadProgrammer appears to be correct. Acoording to the [Oracle's page about Look and Feels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available), HP, IBM and Apple provide their own Look and Feels. 
To my understanding, this clears Oracle's responsability over the out of date L&F, and transfers it to Apple itself.
The only foreseeable option is to wait for updates...